# PHP SELECT where

Tags: php, sql

First of all sorry for my bad english.

I have a php script that display a list of products from sql:

```
$cerereSQL = 'SELECT * FROM `produse`'; 
   $rezultat = mysql_query($cerereSQL);
   while($rand = mysql_fetch_array($rezultat)){
echo '
<form action="editare.php" method="post">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspace="0">
<tr style="text-align:center;" height="25">
<td style="border:1px solid black;" width="7%" height="10"><i> '.$rand['indice'].' </i></td>
<td style="border:1px solid black;" width="40%"><i> '.$rand['denumire_produs'].' </i></td>
<td style="border:1px solid black;" width="20%"><i> '.$rand['producator'].' </i></td>
<td style="border:1px solid black;" width="10%"><i> '.$rand['pret'].' </i></td>
<td style="border:1px solid black;" width="6%"><i> '.$rand['valuta'].' </i></td>
<td style="border:1px solid black;" ><i> '.$rand['cod'].' </i></td>
<td width="5%"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>';
```

I want the button (value="Edit") from the end of each row to select exactly the product from the same row, to be edited.

I tried next code but did't work (i have a list with 5000 lines):

```
switch($_GET['actiune'])
{
case '':

$cerereSQL = 'SELECT * FROM `produse` WHERE denumire_produs="'.$rand['denumire_produs'].'"';
```

I know i have to use: `$cerereSQL = 'SELECT * FROM`produse`WHERE denumire_produs="......";` but i don't know how to do this, how to make the edit button, open the exactly product from the same row.
Can someone please help me with a suggestion?

Comment: MySQL_* functions are deprecated in favor of mysqli_* and PDO.

See: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you mean to do this:

```
$cerereSQL = 'SELECT * FROM `produse`'; 
   $rezultat = mysql_query($cerereSQL);
   while($rand = mysql_fetch_array($rezultat)){
echo '
<form action="editare.php" method="post">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspace="0">
<tr style="text-align:center;" height="25">
<td style="border:1px solid black;" width="7%" height="10"><i> '.$rand['indice'].' </i></td>
<td style="border:1px solid black;" width="40%"><i> '.$rand['denumire_produs'].' </i></td>
<td style="border:1px solid black;" width="20%"><i> '.$rand['producator'].' </i></td>
<td style="border:1px solid black;" width="10%"><i> '.$rand['pret'].' </i></td>
<td style="border:1px solid black;" width="6%"><i> '.$rand['valuta'].' </i></td>
<td style="border:1px solid black;" ><i> '.$rand['cod'].' </i></td>
<td width="5%"><input type="hidden" name="denumire_produs" value="'.$rand['denumire_produs'].'"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>';
```

Then, snag the `denumire_produs` from `$_POST`:

```
$denumire_produs = intval($_POST['denumire_produs']); // is this an INTeger? Otherwise, use `mysql_real_escape_string` -- or use PDO prepared statements.
$cerereSQL = 'SELECT * FROM `produse` WHERE denumire_produs="'.$denumire_produs.'"';
```

Is this what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Four Things

First You dun need single Quotes around table name

```
$cerereSQL = 'SELECT * FROM produse';
```

Second Dont use mysql it is deprecated unless you really need to do

third you need to do this while you are echo any thing like that `method=\"POST\"` your code will not execute due to that

four you need hidden field 
like that

```
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"demuire\" value=\"'.$ran['whatever'].'\"/>
<td width="5%"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit"></td>
```

then you can get this by simple

```
$_POST['demuire']
```